# Displaying of a subset of options in a select tag using classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got two *select* tags and the contents of the first govern the contents of the second. At this point, it's resolved so that when a selection fires an even, the latter is repopulated with new values.

I'm thinking of populating it with all the items but only setting style to visible on the ones that correspond to the former's selection. However, I noticed that the following didn't affect the appearance.

```
return "<option"
  + " style='display: none;'"
  + " value=" + value
  + ">" + text + "</option>"
```

How can I achieve what I wish?

Comment: why do you want to fill all values in the latter one at once ?

Comment: [It actually works hiding with a direct style or a class in Firefox and Chrome, but IE10 is not honoring it.](http://jsfiddle.net/3A4TZ/1/)

Comment: Have you considered using `<optgroup>` instead?

Comment: @NitinKabra Just checking if it can be done. I like resolving stuff using classes (add/remove/toggle), instead of generating HTML tags on the fly.

Comment: @cimmanon Yes, I have. It didn't work neither (the hiding part, that is).

Comment: Optgroup isn't supposed to hide anything.

Comment: @cimmanon Ah, now I see what you were aiming at. In this particular case, I mustn't display the options that aren't related to the selection of the first control. I'm strictly looking for way to **hide** some of the elements. I guess, that's not possible - I'll need to regenerate it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**<strike>Sometimes</strike> Many times IE just really stinks.** So `display: none;` [works fine in other browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/3A4TZ/1/), but basically the [only valid way to "hide" it in IE is to comment it out](http://jsfiddle.net/3A4TZ/6/) (which is cross browser). So you would need to have your code be:

```
return "<!--<option"
  + " style='display: none;'"
  + " value=" + value
  + ">" + text + "</option>-->"
```

However, then the question is, does that really help you at all? Or is it just better to populate the values on the fly as you were doing.

Comment: Oh, this was a retro type of feeling... I though IE had matured **enough** the last few years. Thanks for the answer (+1, of course). And as you so insightfully predicted - no, that doesn't help me at all. I'll need to repopulate the whole shabang.   :)

Comment: By the way - I'm not sure if you noticed that. I checked out your fiddle and one can't **see** the other options but one can still **reach** them. See for yourself - if you select an option and use the arrow keys, you will scroll through them all.   :)

Comment: Oh, that seems to be a bit of a bug in the FF and Chrome implementations, doesn't it? Interesting. Thanks for pointing it out!